# IBM Worklight 6.1.0.1 - worklightserverhost attribute and app-builder

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

How is the worklightserverhost attribute on the app-builder task used? This is important as when deploying an tested application into a production environment, you normally wouldn't do a new build (as this could introduce regression problems). However, the fact that this is a mandatory property and contains in this scenario the test server URL and context - does it force you then to do a new build for the production environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a re-build for each environment does seem to be the usual approach. While we might prefer a "build once, promote through the stages" pattern, I think by careful use of tagging in your source repository you can get pretty good defence against regression.

Alternatively, I think with care you could set up your network so that the app is built once directing to, say,

```
myco.mobile.hostv21
```

you could then have that resolve to the different stages as appropriate.